# how do I redirect to razorpay payment popup after login?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, razorpay

I have created a page in which I have integrated razorpay and created an authentication system. So this is how it works: CLick on payment button => Login Page (if not logged in) => After login redirect back to prev page => Again click on payment button and then razorpay popup shows.

I want to know if there is any way by which we can keep the popup open as soon as the user is redirected back to the previous page without again clicking on payment button?

I have used react.js on frontend and node.js as backend

Answer (score 4):

You can handle it by adding in address string param like:

```
?open_payment=true
```

and then when you will return you will check this and call payment function to open payment.

Comment: Do you want me to add parameters while redirecting to prev route?